# Using parfor in matlab for nested loops

Tags: matlab

I want to parallelize block2 for each block1 and parallerlize outer loop too.

previous code:

> ```
>     for i=rangei
>         <block1>
>         for j=rangej
>             <block2> dependent on <block1>
>         end
>     end
> ```

changed code:

> ```
>     parfor i=rangei
>         <block1>
>         parfor j=rangej
>             <block2> dependent on <block1>
>         end
>     end
> ```

how much efficient can this get and will the changed code do the right thing?
Is the changed code valid for my requirements?

Answer (score 5):

In MATLAB, `parfor` cannot be nested. Which means, in your code, you should replace one `parfor`  by a `for` (the outer loop most likely). More generally, I advise you to look at this [tutorial on parfor](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2009/10/02/using-parfor-loops-getting-up-and-running/).

Answer (score 4):

`parfor` cannot be nested. In nested `parfor` statements, only the outermost call to `parfor` is paralellized, which means that the inner call to `parfor` only adds unnecessary overhead.

To get high efficiency with `parfor`, the number of iterations should be much higher than the number of workers (or an exact multiple in case each iteration takes the same time), and you want a single iteration to take more than just a few milliseconds to avoid feeling the overhead from paralellization.

```
parfor i=rangei
    <block1>
    for j=rangej
        <block2> dependent on <block1>
    end
end
```

may actually fit that description, depending on the size of `rangei`. Alternatively, you may want to try unrolling the nested loop into a single loop, where you iterate across linear indices.

Comment: Actually, one can observe that parfor loop iterations are chunked - so each iteration need not be so tiny. There are, of course, plenty of other factors in play, mostly to do with the overhead of transferring the data.

Answer (score 1):

The following code uses a single `parfor` loop to implicitly manage two nested loops. The `loop1_index` and `loop2_index` are the ranges, and the `loop1_counter` and `loop2_counter` are the actual loop iterators. Also, the iterators are put in reverse order in order to have a better load balance, because usually the load of higher range values is bigger than those of smaller values.

```
loop1_index = [1:5]
loop2_index = [1:4]

parfor temp_label_parfor = 1 : numel(loop1_index) * numel(loop2_index)
    [loop1_counter, loop2_counter] = ind2sub([numel(loop1_index), numel(loop2_index)], temp_label_parfor)
    loop1_counter = numel(loop1_index) - loop1_counter + 1;
    loop2_counter = numel(loop2_index) - loop2_counter + 1;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use nested parfor, From your question it seems that you are working on a matrix( with parameter i,j), 
try using **blockproc**, go through this link once [blockproc](http://www.mathworks.in/help/images/ref/blockproc.html)