# How to nest multiple parfor loops

Tags: matlab, nested-loops, parfor

`parfor` is a convenient way to distribute independent iterations of intensive computations among several "workers". One meaningful restriction is that `parfor`-loops cannot be nested, and invariably, that is the answer to similar questions like [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13444745/converting-nested-for-loops-to-parfor-loop-matlab) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19193542/using-parfor-in-matlab-for-nested-loops).

**Why parallelization across loop boundaries is so desirable**

Consider the following piece of code where iterations take a highly variable amount of time on a machine that allows 4 workers. Both loops iterate over 6 values, clearly hard to share among 4.

```
for row = 1:6
    parfor col = 1:6
        somefun(row, col);
    end
end
```

It seems like a good idea to choose the inner loop for `parfor` because individual calls to `somefun` are more variable than iterations of the outer loop. But what if the run time for each call to `somefun` is very similar? What if there are trends in run time and we have three nested loops? These questions come up regularly, and people go to [extremes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19844249/predicting-runtime-of-parallel-loop-using-a-priori-estimate-of-effort-per-iteran).

**Pattern needed for combining loops**

Ideally, `somefun` is run for all pairs of `row` and `col`, and workers should get busy irrespectively of which iterand is being varied. The solution should look like

```
parfor p = allpairs(1:6, 1:6)
    somefun(p(1), p(2));
end
```

Unfortunately, even if I knew which builtin function creates a matrix with all combinations of `row` and `col`, MATLAB would complain with an error *The range of a parfor statement must be a row vector.* Yet, `for` would not complain and nicely iterate over columns. An easy workaround would be to create that matrix and then index it with `parfor`:

```
p = allpairs(1:6, 1:6);
parfor k = 1:size(pairs, 2)
    row = p(k, 1);
    col = p(k, 2);
    somefun(row, col);
end
```

What is the builtin function in place of `allpairs` that I am looking for? Is there a convenient *idiomatic pattern* that someone has come up with?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

MrAzzman already pointed out how to linearise nested loops. Here is a general solution to linearise n nested loops.

1) Assuming you have a simple nested loop structure like this:

```
%dummy function for demonstration purposes
f=@(a,b,c)([a,b,c]);

%three loops
X=cell(4,5,6);
for a=1:size(X,1);
    for b=1:size(X,2);
        for c=1:size(X,3);
            X{a,b,c}=f(a,b,c);
        end
    end
end
```

2) Basic linearisation using a for loop:

```
%linearized conventional loop
X=cell(4,5,6);
iterations=size(X);
for ix=1:prod(iterations)
    [a,b,c]=ind2sub(iterations,ix);
    X{a,b,c}=f(a,b,c);
end
```

3) Linearisation using a parfor loop.

```
%linearized parfor loop
X=cell(4,5,6);
iterations=size(X);
parfor ix=1:prod(iterations)
    [a,b,c]=ind2sub(iterations,ix);
    X{ix}=f(a,b,c);
end
```

4) Using the second version with a conventional for loop, the order in which the iterations are executed is altered. If anything relies on this you have to reverse the order of the indices.

```
%linearized conventional loop
X=cell(4,5,6);
iterations=fliplr(size(X));
for ix=1:prod(iterations)
    [c,b,a]=ind2sub(iterations,ix);
    X{a,b,c}=f(a,b,c);
end
```

Reversing the order when using a `parfor` loop is irrelevant. You can not rely on the order of execution at all. If you think it makes a difference, you can not use `parfor`.

Comment: Using `prod` and `ind2sub` for packing and unpacking iterands makes this really neat.

Comment: I found some time difference in your said approach, please check, `tic;
for a=1:4
    for b=1:5
       f(a)=sum(a,b);
    end
end
toc;
 tic;
iterations=[5,4];
for ix=1:prod(iterations)
    [b,a]=ind2sub(iterations,ix);
    f(a)=sum(a,b);
end
toc;`

Comment: @USER: That is absolutely right, the linearised loop has a higher overhead, but combining it with `parfor` and some more complex calculation this solution is typically faster.

Comment: @Daniel What if my loops increments in values different than 1?

Like this:

parfor ii = 1 : 10
    for j = 1 : 4 : 9
        for k = 1 : 0.3 : 2
            for l = 5 : 40 : 200

Comment: @Trmotta: You can convert any index to integer indices. Instead of `for j = 1 : 4 : 9`  you use `j_list=1 : 4 : 9;for j_index=1:numel(j_list),j=j_list(j_index),end`.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to do this with `bsxfun`. I *believe* that `bsxfun` will parallelise code where possible (see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/95958) for more information), in which case you should be able to do the following:

```
bsxfun(@somefun,(1:6)',1:6);
```

You would probably want to benchmark this though.

Alternatively, you could do something like the following:

```
function parfor_allpairs(fun, num_rows, num_cols)

parfor i=1:(num_rows*num_cols)
    fun(mod(i-1,num_rows)+1,floor(i/num_cols)+1);
end
```

then call with:

```
parfor_allpairs(@somefun,6,6);
```

Comment: Thank you. I like the second alternative using the product of the upper bounds. It seems to be more flexible than using `bsxfun`, for example in a block of scripted code.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answers from *@DanielR* and *@MrAzzaman*, I am posting two functions, **`iterlin`** and **`iterget`** in place of `prod` and `ind2sub` that allow iteration over ranges also if those do not start from one. An example for the pattern becomes

```
rng = [1, 4; 2, 7; 3, 10];
parfor k = iterlin(rng)
    [plate, row, col] = iterget(rng, k);
    % time-consuming computations here %
end
```

The script will process the wells in rows 2 to 7 and columns 3 to 10 on plates 1 to 4 without any workers idling while more wells are waiting to be processed. In hope that this helps someone, I deposited `iterlin` and `iterget` at the [MATLAB File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/44561-iterlin-and-iterget).

Comment: Hello, I'v seen ur functions and their example, Can u please tell me is `parfor` in ur function needs to `parpool` or `matlabpool` opening? how to check its efficiency by `tic toc`

Comment: Can you please provide an example where you are putting the computation output into X{k} for each combination of plate, row and col? How would I afterward access the result for row=3, col=4, and plate=2, for example?