# Is there a more elegant way to write these loops?

Tags: matlab, coding-style

I have a script that requires a handful of parameters to run.  I'm interested in exploring the results as the parameters change, so I define a few `scan` arrays at the top, wrap the whole code in multiple `for loops` and set the parameters values to the current scan values.

This is error prone and inelegant. The process for changing the code is: 1) reset `scan` variables at the top, 2) comment out eg `b = scan2(j2)` and 3) uncomment `b=b0`.

**What's a better method to allow variables to be set to arrays, and subsequently run the code for all such combinations?**  Example of my code now:

```
close all
clear all

%scan1 = linspace(1,4,10);
scan1 = 0;
scan2 = linspace(0,1,10);
scan3 = linspace(-1,0,10);

for j3 = 1:length(scan3)
  for j2 = 1:length(scan2)
    for j1 = 1:length(scan1)

      a = a0;
      %b = scan2(j2);
      b = b0;
      %c = c0;
      c = scan3(j3);
      d = scan2(j2);

      %(CODE BLOCK THAT DEPENDS ON variables a,b,c,d...)

    end

  end

end
```

Comment: There is no general rule at this point. The vectorization of a code depends pretty much on what exactly is going on in the loops, e.g. matrix multiplication, summation or something else.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not actually trying to vectorize this, I just want better organization.  I could for example make a 1xN array for each parameter at the top, avoiding the commenting out business, but I'm a bit concerned about memory usage... and it seems unnecessary to have a triple for loop when often I only loop on 1 scan.

Comment: I try to understand your code, is there a specific reason to enumerate the `scan` variables different than your parameters? Couldn't you rename them to `scana` `scanb` etc and the iterators to `ja` `jb` etc?

Comment: @Daniel That's a possibility, but then I'd need n nested loops, one for each a,b,c...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [this idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20295693/2732801) to use one for loop to simulate multiple loops, I tried to adapt it to your case. While fulfilling a good memory efficiency and usability, this solution is slower than using individual for loops.

```
%define your parameters
p.a = 1;
p.b = linspace(1,4,4);
p.c = linspace(11,15,5);
p.d = linspace(101,104,4);
p.e = 5;
iterations=structfun(@numel,p);
iterator=cell(1,numel(iterations));
for jx = 1:prod(iterations)
    [iterator{:}]=ind2sub(iterations(:).',jx);%.'
    %This line uses itertor to extract the corresponding elemets of p and creates a struct which only contains scalars.
    q=cell2struct(cellfun(@(a,b)(a(b)),struct2cell(p),iterator(:),'uniform',false),fieldnames(p));
    %__ (CODE THAT DEPENDS ON q.a to q.e here) __

end
```

For the scenarios I tested it adds an computation overhead below `0.0002`s per iteration which is `0.0002.*prod(iterations)`s in total.

Comment: Very cool!  I assume this is slower because of the `structure`?  In my case, speed is not an issue for the wrapper loops: I have code inside that takes orders of magnitude more time, so this would be an option.

Comment: Cell arrays, struct, calling ind2sub, all these three things add an overhead compared to a pure for loop of roughly 0.002s per iteration.

Comment: Do you mean `ind2sub(iterations(:).',j)` instead of `ind2sub(iterations(:).',3)` in the first line of the loop?

Answer (score 0):

One method is to make a single vector that contains all the parameter combinations, using ndgrid.  For a sufficiently large parameter scans this may become a memory concern, but otherwise is at least much cleaner, requiring only a single loop and no re-assignments later in the code:

```
a0vec = 1;
b0vec = linspace(1,4,4);
c0vec = linspace(11,15,5);
d0vec = linspace(101,104,4);
e0vec = 5;

[a0s,b0s,c0s,d0s,e0s] = ndgrid(a0vec,b0vec,c0vec,d0vec,e0vec);    
N = numel(a0s);

for j = 1:N

    a0 = a0s(j);
    b0 = b0s(j);
    c0 = c0s(j);
    d0 = d0s(j);
    e0 = e0s(j);

    %__ (CODE THAT DEPENDS ON a0 - e0 here) __

end
```

Would still like to see your suggestions!

Comment: Since your profile says `python`: how about using that language and a generator, to avoid storing all those values in memory?:) On a related note: what kinds of stuff goes on in the loop? Something complicated, or perhaps vectorizable?

Comment: @AndrasDeak good suggestion!  And a quick look suggests that matlab doesn't have generator-like syntax.  As for memory, I just ran the numbers and 100x100x100 grid x 20 doubles takes up less than .2 gig, so this will work in my case.  The code is ~1,000 lines, this is really a question of good coding practice!

Comment: Indeed, I'm certain MATLAB can't support anything like generators. If your parameter space is always that small, your answer seems quite reasonable.