# Dynamically change for-loops in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop, dynamic

When setting up for-loops, I want to be able to loop over an unknown number of parameters.

Through an input file, the user can set up as many or as few looping parameters as they desire, and I want to be able to loop over them regardless of the number of parameters they set up. Loop Input Example: (Note that my inputs can be lists of strings and number combinations as well)

> Case 1:
>
> - Weight  45000:5000:75000
> - Altitude   10000
> - Speed   0.2:0.1:0.9
>
> Case 2:
>
> - Weight 30000
> - Altitude 1000:1000:10000
> - Flaps 10, 20
> - Temperature  -10:1:10

The length of the list can differ, and can include anywhere from 0-15 variables. I know the workaround, but it's really messy to use a bunch of nested for-loops to do this. I'm looking for a way to set up a method, maybe with Recursion, where the code will set up an appropriate for-loop system regardless of the number of parameters involved, and still keeping track of those variables.

Comment: Are you looking for [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34840222/2732801)?

Comment: I would parse the input file and pass the results as arguments to the function.

Comment: not really necessary to do any parsing. just write the code to use the maximum number of loops (e.g., loop over weight, altitude, speed, temperature, flaps, etc.). in the case where one of the parameters is constant it will effectively not loop but just set the index once and move to the next loop.

Comment: @transversality condition I parse my data appropriately and send it into the loops as a structure. My current setup is essentially what you described, but I'm looking for something more elegant and flexible - what if a new variable is added that I didn't foresee? I want the code to be able to handle that seamlessly.

Comment: @excaza I do exactly as you say, but this is the parsing stage. I want to be able to parse any number of inputs appropriately before I send them to my function for calculations and such.

Comment: @Daniel at first glance, that solution seems to work pretty well with my situation, however I still have to test it more with the variety of cases i can have. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @arthream It is good SO etiquette to accept an answer if you feel one addressed your question well. There's a check box next to each answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion.

You haven't put any speed requirements on this.  This answer is slow, uses memory poorly, but is the simplest possible implementation of this idea.  Many better implementations exist that are more complicated, use much less memory, and are significantly faster.  Depends on how tight you need the inner loops to be...

```
parms.weight = [45000:5000:75000];
parms.alt    = 10000;
parms.Speed  = 0.2:0.1:0.9;
```

Then, define your simulator, as something like:

```
function result = simulation(parms)
    fieldNames = fieldnames(parms)
    result = [];
    for ix = 1 : numel(fieldNames)
       if 1 < numel(parms.(fieldNames{ix})) 
           list = parms.(fieldNames{ix});
           for jx = 1 : numel(list)
                tmpParms = parms;
                tmpParms.(fieldNames{ix}) = list(jx);
                tmpResult = simulation(tmpParms);
                result = [result; tmpResult];
           end
           return;
        end
     end

     if 0 == numel(result)
         % Do the real simulation here.
     end
```

Comment: I have often been faced with this problem, but for some reason your question spurred me on to a whole new way of thinking about it.  Excellent question.

Comment: There is something wrong with your code, I get by far to many combinations. Just try `struct('a',[1 2],'b',[3],'c',[4,5],'e',[6,7])`. Would expect 6 calls of the simulation but it generates much more calls.

Comment: @Daniel, thanks.  You are right there is a bug.  Fixed.  btw. with your inputs, expect 8 results in the final answer.  Note: The number of distinct calls to simulation will be larger than 8.

Answer (score 2):

**The code-generation solution**

Well, you already have a number of pretty good solutions. I'll just toss one in there that involves code generation. MATLAB doesn't really have much in the way of those kind of tools, but you can fake it with a few loops and `fprintf`. Here's my code generation script:

```
s = struct() ;
s.weight = 45000:5000:75000 ;
s.altitude = 10000 ;
s.engine = {'ge','rolsroyce'} ;

h = fopen('thisrun.m','w+') ;

mydisp = @(varargin)disp(transpose(varargin(:))) ; % dummy function body

vars = fields(s) ;
nv = numel(vars) ;

for ii = 1:nv
    if isnumeric(s.(vars{ii}))
        lb = '(' ;
        rb = ')' ;
    else
        lb = '{' ;
        rb = '}' ;
    end
    fprintf(h,'for i%g = 1:numel(s.(vars{%g})) \n',ii,ii) ;
    fprintf(h,'i%gval = s.(vars{%g})%si%g%s ; \n',ii,ii,lb,ii,rb) ;
end

fprintf(h,'mydisp(') ;
for ii = 1:numel(vars)
    fprintf(h,'i%gval',ii) ;
    if ii<nv
        fprintf(h,',') ;
    end
end
fprintf(h,') ; \n') ;

for ii = 1:nv
    fprintf(h,'end \n') ;
end

fclose(h) ;
run thisrun.m
```

Generated code (`thisrun.m`):

```
for i1 = 1:numel(s.(vars{1}))
    i1val = s.(vars{1})(i1) ;
    for i2 = 1:numel(s.(vars{2}))
        i2val = s.(vars{2})(i2) ;
        for i3 = 1:numel(s.(vars{3}))
            i3val = s.(vars{3}){i3} ;
            mydisp(i1val,i2val,i3val) ;
        end
    end
end
```

Result of running generated code:

```
>>
    [45000]    [10000]    'ge'

    [45000]    [10000]    'rolsroyce'

    [50000]    [10000]    'ge'

    [50000]    [10000]    'rolsroyce'

    [55000]    [10000]    'ge'

    [55000]    [10000]    'rolsroyce'

    [60000]    [10000]    'ge'

    [60000]    [10000]    'rolsroyce'

    [65000]    [10000]    'ge'

    [65000]    [10000]    'rolsroyce'

    [70000]    [10000]    'ge'

    [70000]    [10000]    'rolsroyce'

    [75000]    [10000]    'ge'

    [75000]    [10000]    'rolsroyce'
```

The code generation takes time, but if you need to run the file many times it might still be an efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

Doing nested `for`-loops for all parameters is the simple solution, constant parameters will simply result in a single iteration for that specific loop.

You could also use [`ndgrid`](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) to create a set of multi-dimensional arrays that are the parameters for each call of your `computeFunction(...)`, and iterate over the `ngrid's` output instead of building nested for loops for each potentially variable parameter, if you expect to change the number of parameters.

However, be aware that it might come at a performance cost, as depending on what exactly you do in which matlab version, it might not benefit from the builtin optimizations the 'simple' for-loop version gets.

Comment: You bring up a very useful point about performance. Thanks a lot for your input!

Comment: Also, and correct me if I'm wrong, it seems that ndgrid is limited to numeric values only, which doesn't help my situation. I could build an indexed lookup for the string inputs, but that's more complication that I would like to add to the code.

Comment: @arthream: The primary disadvantage of this solution is, that it builds up a matrix with the complete parameter space (each combination), that might use to much memory.

Comment: @arthream: The requirement to use strings is something you should have mentioned in your question! Please update your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recursive function that produces all possible sets of parameters as column vectors of an array:

```
function idx=dynloop(varargin)
    if nargin==1
        idx=varargin{1};
    else
        idx=dynloop(varargin{2:end});
        idx=[repelem(varargin{1},size(idx,2));
             repmat(idx,[1,length(varargin{1})])];
    end
return
```

**Example output:** loop over `5:7`, then `8`, then `[2,3,5,7]`:

```
 >> idx = dynloop(5:7,8,[2,3,5,7])

idx =

     5     5     5     5     6     6     6     6     7     7     7     7
     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8
     2     3     5     7     2     3     5     7     2     3     5     7
```

The output is equivalent to that of `ndgrid`, (except in my opinion more intuitively shaped). (Also some preliminary benchmarking showed this may be *slightly faster than* `ndgrid`...?! To be determined)

**Main loop:** Now just use one loop to iterate through the columns of `idx`. Note this solution concept is similar to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34839668/is-there-a-more-elegant-way-to-write-these-loops/34840222#34840222), as commented by @Daniel on the OP.

```
Weight   = 45000:5000:75000;
Altitude = 10000;
Speed    = 0.2:0.1:0.9;

idx = dynloop(Weight,Altitude,Speed);

for ii=1:size(idx,2)
    params = idx(:,ii);

    %// do stuff with params! 
    %// ...

end
```

**EDIT: to handle both string and numeric inputs**

A simple mod to the original recursive function I posted allows it to return indices, rather than actual elements, so string cells are fine:

```
function idx=dynloop(varargin)
    if nargin==1
        idx=1:length(varargin{1});
    else
        idx=dynloop(varargin{2:end});
        idx=[repelem(1:length(varargin{1}),size(idx,2));
             repmat(idx,[1,length(varargin{1})]);];
    end
return
```

So altogether, your function would presumably operate like this:

```
function yourMainFcn(varargin)
    idx=dynloop(varargin{:});
    for ii=1:size(idx,2)
        params = cellfun(@(x,k) numORcell(x,k),...
                 varargin,num2cell(idx(:,ii).'),... %//'
                 'UniformOutput',0);

        %// do stuff with params! 
        %// ...
        disp(params)

    end
end
```

where the function `numORcell` appropriately parses numeric versus cell data:

```
function y=numORcell(x,k)
    if iscell(x)
        y=x{k};
    else
        y=x(k);
    end
end
```

**Example with strings:**

```
Weight   = 45000:5000:75000;
Altitude = 10000;
Speed    = 0.2:0.1:0.9;
Names    = {'Foo','Bar'};

>> yourMainFcn(Names,Altitude,Weight)
'Foo'    [10000]    [45000]

'Foo'    [10000]    [50000]

'Foo'    [10000]    [55000]

'Foo'    [10000]    [60000]

'Foo'    [10000]    [65000]

'Foo'    [10000]    [70000]

'Foo'    [10000]    [75000]

'Bar'    [10000]    [45000]

'Bar'    [10000]    [50000]

'Bar'    [10000]    [55000]

'Bar'    [10000]    [60000]

'Bar'    [10000]    [65000]

'Bar'    [10000]    [70000]

'Bar'    [10000]    [75000]
```

or instead:

```
>> yourMainFcn(Names,Names,Speed,Names)
'Foo'    'Foo'    [0.2]    'Foo'

'Foo'    'Foo'    [0.2]    'Bar'

'Foo'    'Foo'    [0.3]    'Foo'

'Foo'    'Foo'    [0.3]    'Bar'

'Foo'    'Foo'    [0.4]    'Foo'

...

'Foo'    'Foo'    [0.9]    'Bar'

'Foo'    'Bar'    [0.2]    'Foo'

...

'Foo'    'Bar'    [0.9]    'Bar'

'Bar'    'Foo'    [0.2]    'Foo'

...

'Bar'    'Foo'    [0.9]    'Bar'

...

'Bar'    'Bar'    [0.8]    'Foo'

'Bar'    'Bar'    [0.8]    'Bar'

'Bar'    'Bar'    [0.9]    'Foo'

'Bar'    'Bar'    [0.9]    'Bar'
```

**Exercise left to the reader:** If storing all the indices in `idx` is a memory issue, you must be doing some pretty heavy looping. Nonetheless, you can create a function that determines from the current index set the next lexicographical index set, meaning you would only have to store one set of indices and iterate at the end of each loop.

Comment: Interesting. I should have also specified that my input parameters can include strings and alphanumeric values, and ndgrid isn't the best method with string inputs.. unless I come up with a complicated scheme of indexing the string options in large lists. But the key is complicated. 
It's a priority that I make the code understandable for future users.

Comment: @arthream my solution has been edited to handle string inputs as well. It does not require you index the string options yourself. I hope it helps

Comment: thanks a lot! This edit should work nicely, except that I am running MATLAB version 2014b (repelem was introduces in 2015a), and my code is supposed to be compatible with at least as far back as 2012a. This is definitely insightful, and I will keep it in mind!

Comment: @arthream You can work around `repelem` pretty easily: `reshape(repmat(1:length(varargin{1}),[size(idx,2),1]),[1,length(varargin{1})*size(idx,2)])` ... it looks complicated but if you digest it from the inside-out I hope you can make sense of it